# Cross products and orthogonal complements

Tags: orthogonality, cross-product

I am having trouble with this question about cross products and orthogonality:

Let a ∈ R3 \ {0}

Show that if y ⊥ a then $\exists$ x {x ∈ R3 : a × x = y}

Could anyone explain this to me? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you can always make  $v = y \times a/|a|$ and then $a \times v /|a|$ will give $y$, so $x = v/|a| = y \times a/|a|^2$

Comment: Could you explain this a little more?

Comment: sorry, there was a mistake in the previous editing. Is it clear now?

Comment: how do you rearrange $v = y \times a/|a|$ to $y = a \times v /|a|$?

Comment: To explain a bit further, since $y$ is orthogonal to $a$ then $v = y \times a / |a|$ is orthogonal to both, and has modulus =$y$. Now take $a/|a|$ which has unit modulus, multiply by $v$ and you return to $y$, paying attention to the "right hand" rule. To get $x$ then you just shift over to $v$ the $/|a$ which is a scalar. The whole is equivalent to the answer by @Carlos Ajila, but in  "engineering" terms.

Answer (score 1):

Write $ y = y_1e_1+y_2e_2 + y_3e_3 $ and $ a = a_1e_1 + a_2e_2 + a_3e_3 $, where $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ is the canonical basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$. Consider the matrix

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & a_3 & -a_2\\ -a_3 & 0 & a_1\\ a_2 & -a_1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

and prove that the any non-trivial solution of $Ax = y$ is the $x$ you are looking for.

Comment: I'm having trouble following this, after expanding out $Ax = y$ is that enough to show that there exists an x that satisfies the equation?

Comment: When you expand $Ax=y$ you find that it is equivalent to have $a\times x = y$, and this means that solve the equation $a\times x=y$ is the same as solve the linear system $Ax=y$.